# Facebook pinging deauthorize callback url with the wrong request

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-apps

I'm working on a facebook tab app. I need to know when the user uninstall the tab app from their page so that I can update my database. While facebook documentation do not specify how that can be accomplished I read that facebook would ping your deauthorize callback url.

On facebook documentation, they say that they will ping the url with a post request sending a signed_request (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logout), but whenever I remove the tab app from a page facebook send a GET request to my callback url without any signed_request, which doesn't help me to know which page had the app uninstalled.

[Access log from my apache server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qevQs.png)

The 302 redirect is happening because there is no signed request.

What should I do? I can't query all the pages on my database to find out which one had the tab uninstalled because it wouldn't scale, I would need the manage_pages permission and there is no way, without a signed request, to know that the request came from facebook.

Comment: I am not sure that the deauthorize callback should even be called in this situation – what you are referring to is for when _users_ uninstall your app. Removing a page tab app is not the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I always thought that the deauthorize callback would only be called when the user uninstall the app, but since I saw on the web people saying that facebook would use this when the tab app is removed I decided to give it a try.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/379/facebook-deauthorize-callback-url-and-its-response-data/

Facebook does ping you from what I have seen but without any information. If you know any other way  to get a notification when a page administer removes your app it would help me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the callback URL to SSL. We had this issue earlier this year and when sending to http:// it was always a GET request but once we changed it to https:// it was changed back to a POST request with the signed_request in the body.